# the mysterious schedule 2

Tags: ios, iphone

In the [iOS Developer Program License Agreement](https://developer.apple.com/programs/terms/ios/standard/ios_program_standard_agreement_20120912.pdf) there is a mysterious reference to something called "Schedule 2". The closest I can find to a source is this vague sentence:

> available separately to cover distribution of paid-for Licensed
>   Applications via the App Store

Anyone have any idea where on earth this thing is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To view Schedule 2, go to http://itunesconnect.apple.com/ and log in.  Then click on the “Agreements, Tax, and Banking” link.  If you have accepted Schedule 2, one of your contracts will be under Contract Region “All (See Contract)”, Contract Type “Paid Applications”.  That contract is Schedule 2.   Download the contract PDF and you will see that it starts out “By Your clicking to agree to this Schedule 2, …”

Comment: bingo. Now I just have to read that thing...

Comment: in 2019 it is at the bottom of "Agreements > Paid Apps" page under "Terms"